# Changing Font Size of Japanese (Unicode) characters

Tags: cocoa, unicode, font-size, nspopupbutton

I have a NSPopUpButton which contains either English or Japanese Strings read from a plist file according to the System's Language. Now when the Language is English I am able to change the font size by using code such as -

```
 [auxStatePopup setFont: [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:10.0]];
```

but Using such technique I am not able to change Japanese font size even if I tried by setting some Japanese font name which I googled and found out.
I want to do that because Japanese characters move slightly up when used. I intend to manipulate that upward movement by decreasing font size.
Thanks for any help..

[image: Japanese alignement problem]

[image]

OR

any way to move text in NSPopupButton downwards?

Comment: It would be a good idea to include some screenshots first.

Comment: @sorin the screenshots have been added. Reflects on some browsers but not on all. It reflects in Opera though.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that the two samples are not using the same font. Please try to put a text with characters from both sets and see what happens.

Also try not to customize the `font size` and even the `font face`.

I also suspect that the text rendering engine may had overridden some of your changes due to the text length. iOS text rendering may try to change the font size of letter spacing if the text does not fit the control. So make some tests with shorter texts.

BTW, I think that you were mean to say that you want bigger font size for Japanese not smaller. In the screenshots the Japanese text is already too small to be properly read by anyone.